# Php Login/registration data stored in txt

Tags: php, authentication, registration

I'm trying to make a simple login/reg, but the login doesn't work, only with the last line of my txt file, probably because of the other lines contain the '\n' on the end of every line, but it worked before, I don't know what went wrong... What do I have to do to make it work? Here's my code:

login.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $file = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
    $good=false;
    while(!feof($file)){
        $line = fgets($file);
        $array = explode(";",$line);
        if($array[0]==$_POST["name"] && $array[1]==$_POST["password"]){
            $good=true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($good){
        $message="Welcome";
    }else{
        $message="Try again";
    }
    include 'message.html';
fclose($file);
}else{
    include 'login.html';
}
?>
```

reg.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
    $f=fopen("data.txt","a");
    fputs($f,$_POST["name"].";".$_POST["password"]."\r\n");
    fclose($f);
}else{
    include 'reg.html';
}
?>
```

And this is how the data.txt looks like:

```
Viktor;1234
Eve;12345
Cathlin;12356
```

Comment: Define 'not working', please. What are you expecting and what are you getting instead? Incidentally, that code is not a very good way of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: If the name and password combination is correct, it should write out "Welcome", as you can see. I keep getting "Try again" for every line, except for the last.

Comment: I see you've edited your question and replaced $uzenet with $message. Did that fix your problem?

Comment: no, it didn't it was just a small fix, translated some words because i'm writing the code in another language, not english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `trim()` to strip away whitespaces from the beginning and end of the strings.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);

    list($user, $pass) = explode(';', $line);

    if(trim($user) == $_POST['name'] && trim($pass) == $_POST['password']){
        $good=true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a demo for PHP registration and login, and tested fine.

This is the reg html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Reg Page   </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>  UserName</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="user" > </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> PassWord  </td>
    <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="reg" value="REG"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The registration php as below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["user"]) && isset($_POST["pass"]))
{
    // check if user exist.
    $file=fopen("data.txt","r");
    $finduser = false;
    while(!feof($file))
    {
        $line = fgets($file);
        $array = explode(";",$line);
        if(trim($array[0]) == $_POST['user'])
        {
            $finduser=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
 
    // register user or pop up message
    if( $finduser )
    {
        echo $_POST["user"];
        echo ' existed!\r\n';
        include 'reg.html';
    }
    else
    {
        $file = fopen("data.txt", "a");
        fputs($file,$_POST["user"].";".$_POST["pass"]."\r\n");
        fclose($file);
        echo $_POST["user"];
        echo " registered successfully!";
    }
}
else
{
    include 'reg.html';
}
?>
```

The login form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Login Page   </title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table width="200" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>  UserName</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="user" > </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> PassWord  </td>
    <td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="login" value="LOGIN"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The login php:

```
<?php  session_start(); ?>  // session starts with the help of this function 
 
<?php
 
if(isset($_SESSION['use']))   // Checking whether the session is already there or not if 
                              // true then header redirect it to the home page directly 
 {
    header("Location:home.php"); 
 }
else
{
    include 'login.html';
}
 
if(isset($_POST['login']))   // it checks whether the user clicked login button or not 
{
     $user = $_POST['user'];
     $pass = $_POST['pass'];
 
    if(isset($_POST["user"]) && isset($_POST["pass"])){
    $file = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
    $good=false;
    while(!feof($file)){
        $line = fgets($file);
        $array = explode(";",$line);
    if(trim($array[0]) == $_POST['user'] && trim($array[1]) == $_POST['pass']){
            $good=true;
            break;
        }
    }
 
    if($good){
    $_SESSION['use'] = $user;
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.open("home.php","_self");</script>';  
    }else{
        echo "invalid UserName or Password";
    }
    fclose($file);
    }
    else{
        include 'login.html';
    }
 
}
?>
```

I put the source code at [here](http://alanzheng.top/doku.php?id=tutorials:tools:php_session_and_login) for reference.